# login info showing up on homepage after successful login

Tags: html, reactjs, firebase-authentication, linkedin-api, google-signin

I am using firebase to get google login and I need help getting the user id that google is assigning to the home page. When someone signs in using their google id they are redirected to my home page. I want the page to also want the display to say hello, xxxxxxx

Here is what i have for the header so far

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { startLogout, googleAuthProvider } from '../actions/auth';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router';


 const Header = ({ startLogout, googleAuthProvider }) => (

<header className="header">


<h1 className="header__title">Journal Example App</h1>
<p>Hello, {googleAuthProvider.login}</p>
<div className="center-spread">
<NavLink to="/" activeClassName="is-active" className="button center-spread" exact={true}>Dashboard</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/create" activeClassName="is-active" className="button center-spread" >Create Topic</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/topics" activeClassName="is-active" className="button center-spread" >Footnotes</NavLink>
<button className="button" onClick={startLogout} >Logout</button>
</div>
</header>

 );

   const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
   startLogout: () => dispatch(startLogout())
   });

   export default connect(undefined, mapDispatchToProps)(Header);
```

why won't the google auth provider give me the username listed? I am using firebase to get the information and this has been driving me crazy for a bit.

Comment: try console.log (googleAuthProvider ) first, what you see?

Comment: it's showing undefined so it shouldn't be where it's getting it's info then...hmmm

Comment: alright so I was looking around and firebase actually has some documentation on defining the current user and then applying whatever it is to whatever you need, and you can even have it do some pretty crazy things like ask for a confirmation email and stuff like that. basically I went off the stuff here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users